# Computational complexity of the following quadratic program (QP)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computational-complexity, quadratic-programming

Let $A^TA$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. 
I have the following quadratic program to solve:
\begin{array}{rl} 
\min \limits_{x} & x^T A^T A x \\
\mbox{subject to} &  \sum_{i=1}^{r} x_i =1, \sum_{i=r+1}^{s} x_i =1 \\
 & x \ge 0
\end{array}
where $n=r+s$

My question: what is the computational complexity of this problem ?

Comment: what do you mean by computational complexity?

Comment: This is explained [_here_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: Most methods are iterative and provide only an approximation to the solution. You can spend as much time on it as you like and you do not know a priori how many steps are needed. The interior point method for example provides a $\epsilon$-approximation in polynomial time depending on $\epsilon$ and number of constraints.

Comment: Using the interior point method, is there any expression for the complexity for a fixed $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: yes, however I only have a german source here. The bound is basically the same as in case of LP. For LP see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700004337

Comment: One more question please. Do you know if there exists a method that can outperform (in terms of complexity) the interior point method?

Comment: you could try projected gradients ... But, I do not know where there are some complexity results.

Comment: May I ask why you are asking? Frankly theoretical complexity is near useless in practice. The complexity measures for interior-point measures, for instance, are terribly conservative: that is, in practice, you'll take far fewer iterations than the theoretical bounds suggest. First-order methods often have less conservative complexity measures, but in this case they'll depend on the condition number of $A$, I'll bet. And the question of whether or not you should *prefer* an interior-point method to a first-order method often depend more on practical factors than theoretical performance.

Comment: Without any assumption on $A$, I'd say you can achieve $\mathcal{O}(\|A\|^2/\sqrt{\epsilon})$ (w.r.t function values) with FISTA (for example). At each step, you've need to project on to the simplexes $\Delta_r$ and $\Delta_n$ (to get the prox of the part of the energy encoding for the feasibility constraints). These projections can be computed effectively using the algorithm described here https://web.stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/DuchiShSiCh08.html.

Comment: Five fake edits, only to push this to the first page of questions. For how long have you been playing this game?

Comment: @Did most of the people play this game! I hope this is not a crime ..

Comment: What? Who is, for example?